# json in Command Prompt

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So I reacently began learning node.js. What I have done so far is to collect some json-data. However I can't target for example "ID" (JSONresponse.id) like I'm able to in "normal in-browser javascript".

I tried to print all the data in the command promt. I googled up a "JSON formater". What i discoverd was that when a line break "interuppted" an "answer" I got an error.  For example

```
.....,
ID: "506
403",
.......,
```

Hopefully you understand what i mean. My question is if this is the problem and wheter it is or it's not how can i solve it? Thanks

Comment: Multi line spanned strings are not allowed in javascript. Your string quotes should terminate on the same line. Or you can use `es6` template literal syntax if you want your strings to go multiple lines.

Comment: You could fix the input file, a new line shouldn't be in there (and if it would, then probably with backtic sign \` instead of what you have double quotes

Comment: You can use multi line spanned string using [`]

Comment: you can use backslash \

Comment: It's weird to see a ... new line in an "ID". Unless those "506" and "403" are separate ID's? In that case, I should use `,` to bring in separation. (Then it's simply `.join(',')` to convert an array to string and  `.split(',')` to go back to array)

Comment: I haven't written the json file. Aslo I'm not even sure it's the problem. What I mean with line break is that I have reached the maximum numbers of cahracters that fits on one row so the "ID" continues to get printed on the line below. Do I make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so one thing you can do is replace all line break characters from your response, after that try to parse the json.

To replace all line breaking characters you can do in this way;

```
jsonResponse=jsonResponse.replace('/\n/g','')
```

The solution is only for if your problem is just because of line breaking characters.

Comment: I haven't written the json file. Aslo I'm not even sure it's the problem. What I mean with line break is that I have reached the maximum numbers of cahracters that fits on one row so the "ID" continues to get printed on the line below. Do I make any sense? Thank you!

Comment: Then also you can try my answer i.e., remove all line braking characters from the response and let me know if it is working.

Comment: No sorry that didn't seem to do it either.

Comment: Now use a json formatter and check what is the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that the program doesn't understand that it's loading a json-file and instead think it's a text file. When i do jsonResponse[0] i should get the first article in the response. Instead I get the first character in the document. Can that be it?

Comment: Do one thing before **jsonResponse[0]** ; i.e, jsonResponse=JSON.parse(jsonResponse)

Comment: Yes! That did it! Not sure what "jsonResponse=JSON.parse(jsonResponse)" means but Ill look it up! Anyways thank you, you did my day :)